# Given a string, how can I use JavaScript to remove all 'HTML tags' except a specific 'tag' (and its 'children')?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Given a **string** resembling HTML **(but not actually HTML)**, how can I use JavaScript to remove all 'HTML tags' except a specific 'tag' (and its 'children')?

For instance, if I have the following **string**:

```
'<p><span>Sample data: <math><msqrt><mo>y</mo></msqrt></math></span> <div><strong>hello world</strong><math><msqrt><mo>x</mo></msqrt></math></div></p>'
```

And I only want to keep raw text & 'math tags' (and everything inside each 'math tag'), how would I go about doing that?

```
const html = '<p><span>Sample data: <math><msqrt><mo>y</mo></msqrt></math></span> <div><strong>hello world</strong><math><msqrt><mo>x</mo></msqrt></math></div></p>';
const result = stripNonSpecifiedHTML(html, 'math');
// expected result:
// 'Sample data: <math><msqrt><mo>y</mo></msqrt></math>hello world<math><msqrt><mo>x</mo></msqrt></math>'

function stripNonSpecifiedHTML(html, tagNameToKeep) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: See [*RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks rather awful, but it woks (with some limitations):

- split the string by `<math>` and `</math>`
- remove all html tags in every second element
- add `<math>` and `</math>` around every second element
- join the array back into a string

```js
const html =
'<p><span>Initial data: <math><msqrt><mo>y</mo></msqrt></math></span> <div><strong>hello world</strong><math><msqrt><mo>x</mo></msqrt></math></div></p>'

var text = html.split('<math>')
           .map(t => t.split('</math>')).flat()
           .map((t, i) => {return (i % 2==0 ) ? t.replace(/<.+?>/g,''): t })
           .map((t, i) => {return (i % 2==0 ) ? t : '<math>' + t + '</math>' })
           .join('');

console.log(text);

// OUTPUT: Initial data: <math><msqrt><mo>y</mo></msqrt></math> hello world<math><msqrt><mo>x</mo></msqrt></math>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
html.split('<math>')[1].split('</math>')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

While not `html`, this string can be parsed as `xml`.

```
const html = '<p><span>Initial data: <math><msqrt><mo>y</mo></msqrt></math></span> <div><math><msqrt><mo>x</mo></msqrt></math></div></p>';

let parser = new DOMParser(),
    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(html, 'text/xml');
```

Then from there, you can loop over all the `<math>` tags.

```
let mathTags = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('math');
Array.from(mathTags).forEach(math => {
    let data = math.innerHTML,
        content = math.textContent;
});
```

Comment: I _think_ you an use `text/html` to parse using HTML5's parsing?

Comment: @loganfsmyth You could do that, and it should work.  I just figured XML might be better if the HTML parser didn't like some of the tags.